# How can I make an svg a background image with the body tag?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am really racking my brain at the moment, because I can't seem to find a way to make an svg into a background image. Currently this is my code:

```
<body style="background:url(images/bg.jpg) fixed; background-size:cover;">
```

But if I change that to an svg I have, it doesnt show the background any more, and if I try and put that into the CSS like this;

```
body {
background: url(images/bg.jpg) fixed;
background-size:cover;
```

it doesn't show up anymore, so it clearly has to be in the HTML unless there is a better way to do it.

Please help!

Thanks

-Dan

Comment: I don't see `svg` anywhere in your code

Comment: what svg? also check http://caniuse.com/svg-css

Comment: Are you sure you closed curly bracket for body tag or not other typo like this? Also check if your css file is in different folder, so you must give path relative to your css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVG images should be supported by the browser in order to display. 
Here I have found a good artical for SVG images and their support: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/